# JUPITER installation problems ..

Tags: battery, jupiter

** PLEASE HELP **

i attempted to install the JUPITER app on 3 different occasions an all i keep getting as end result is ..... Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:webupd8team/jupiter'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.

does anyone hav a link to solve my problem ?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jupiter/ "As of 2013-06-25, this project is no longer under active development." Since I couldn't find the PPA you mention I asume such PPA no longer exist because of the project's death.

Comment: maybe this could help anyway: https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter

Answer (score 1):

According to [the WebUpd8 website](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/jupiter-ubuntu-ppa-hardware-and-power.html):

> Update: Jupiter has been discontinued. I suggest trying [TLP](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html) instead.

To install it, open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run:

```
sudo -i
add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
apt-get update
apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
tlp start
```

Make sure to read [what the WebUpd8 website has to say about TLP](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html) or [what the TLP FAQ says](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html).

---

If you absolutely must have Jupiter, [it's available via the JoliCloud PPA repository](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/jupiter-is-available-for-ubuntu-13-04/).

Note that the following assumes:

- You're using Ubuntu 13.04 or later.
- You're OK with completely unsupported software.
- You realize the software is discontinued.

To install it, open a terminal and run:

```
sudo -i
add-apt-repository -y ppa:jolicloud-team/ppa
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
mv jolicloud-team-ubuntu-ppa-*.list jolicloud-team-ubuntu-ppa.list
sed -i "s/$(lsb_release -cs)/raring/g" jolicloud-team-ubuntu-ppa.list
cd -
apt-get update
apt-fast install jupiter
```

If you're installing to an Asus Eee PC, run the following as well:

```
sudo apt-get install jupiter-support-eee
```

Comment: it seems the commands from the link u provided is installing .. however i can not find the actually app inside on my os, any suggestions as to how to find it ??

Comment: Which one: TLP or Jupiter?